# sphinx generate class modules overview

Tags: python, graph, python-sphinx, graphviz

I'd like sphinx to generate a module overview similar to the one generated by doxygen, here is an [example](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1node_1_1Switch.html)

I can't find how sphinx can do that

I could use Graphviz to generate some sort of graph, but I can't find a way to get a clickable object in the graph that operates in the same way as the example above.

Is there any way to do that in sphinx directly or some hack to make it work as the doxygen module overview?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sphinx has a built-in [extension](http://sphinx-doc.org/extensions.html) called [sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/inheritance.html) that uses Graphviz. It defines one directive: `inheritance-diagram`. Here is an example of how you could use it in an .rst file:

```
.. inheritance-diagram:: mymodule.MyClass1 mymodule.MyClass2
   :parts: 1
```

Here are some examples of inheritance diagrams in documents generated by Sphinx:

- http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/devel/documenting_mpl.html#inheritance-diagrams
- http://openalea.gforge.inria.fr/doc/vplants/PlantGL/doc/_build/html/user/math.html#class-inheritance-diagram

---

There is also a "generic" [sphinx.ext.graphviz](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/graphviz.html#module-sphinx.ext.graphviz) extension for embedding graphs in documentation.