# Python, Sphinx: display superclasses

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've given RTFM a shot, but Sphinx is a big package, and I have a specific question.

I'm looking at docs for an open source project that were generated by Sphinx.  The one thing that would be useful for me right now is to see for each class the list of parent classes up to the top level.  I'm used to seeing this in java docs.  The current docs show only the parent one generation higher.  I've notice that Sphinx has *automodule* and *show_inheritance*,  but it's not clear that this is what I want, nor is it clear how to mod the existing source to use it.

How can I display the parent class hierarchy?  Is there some other means to walk an entire python module and display the entire class hierarchy?

Comment: I've had a good look for this functionality too, and never found anything.  Very interested if someone finds anything.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20548495/407651

Comment: It appears to, especially the last one.  It will take some experimentation to tell.  Thanks.  (Perhaps make this comment an answer?)